# How to add respective user table in my already created users and user_type

Tags: django

When registering user. I populated usertype and registerfrom and created a user with usertype having patient and Doctors. Now, i need a separate table where i can list out the logged in usertype patient in patient table and doctor in doctor table. 
How do I extend user profiles according to user types(role)

```
class UserType(models.Model):
    user =models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    USER_TYPE = (
        (1, 'Patient'),
        (2, 'Doctor'),
    )
    user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE)
```

Also i have a model called bookings
here fields are username department and is in a one to one relation with user

```
    user =models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

so i need to book with logged in user with the doctors. also i need to add a field called specialty for doctors.

Although i have created profile. but when i update it i want to display specific fields for doctor only

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need to use two separated tables to list logged in doctors and patients, if each user has a unique type. You can use only one table:

```
class LoggedInUser(models.Model):
    user_type = models.ForeignKeyField(UserType, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='logged_in')
    logInTimestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

With this model, you can query for all doctors like this: `LoggedInUser.objects.filter(user_type__user_type=2)`.